# Pandas Crosstab when used with Pandas cut : Row names of the output crosstab are mismatched

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, visualization

I have some data with binary (0 and 1) labels. I am using `pd.cut` to discretize one feature `continuous_value`, before doing a `pd.crosstab` on the new field.

The problem is that when I do crosstab, the output seems to mismatch the row names (which are the boundaries for each bin) with the corresponding counts.

Here is my code for a minimal example of the issue. `continuous_value` is non-negative. 118 data points have `continuous_value = 0`, so the smallest bin edge is -1, to include these. In this minimal example, the data is cut into the two bins: (-1 to 0), which only includes those with 0 value, and (0 to 5000000) which includes all other data points.

```
bins=[-1,0,5000000]
input_df['discrete_value']=pd.cut(input_df['continuous_value'],bins=bins)    
pd.crosstab(input_df.discrete_value, input_df.label)
```

As you can see in the attached picture, the bin names are mismatched. The count for the non-zero bin sums to 118, and the count for the zero bin sums to 10237. This should be the other way around.

[image: output]

---

EDIT to include dummy data and code snippet that reproduces the error:

`values = [5100,5400,9400,10000,16000,10500,0,0,0,87500,14000,11250]
d = {'continuous': values,'label': [0]*6+[1]*6}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
bins = [-1, 0, 5000000]
df['discrete'] = pd.cut(df['continuous'], bins=bins)`

[image: Dummy code and error in output]

Comment: I suggest you write a reproduce code

Comment: @parvij could you expand on what you mean by this? Thanks

Comment: a dataset and code which reproduce a similar result

Comment: Can you give a sample of the dataset you use, `continuous_value` specifically? I have a code snippet with some dummy data and it works fine.

Comment: @KenSyme and parvij thanks for your responses -  I have added reproduce code + dummy dataset to my original question including a screenshot of the same problem in output. Thanks.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? `pd.__version__`. I am getting the bin labels the other way round, and so correct, with your code... Can you make sure to try restarting the kernel on Jupyter and retry your sample query?

Comment: @KenSyme Pandas version = '0.23.0' . Just tried `conda update pandas` in Anaconda command prompt and got the message 'All requested packages already installed'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Pandas version 0.23.0. In the latest version, 0.23.2, it correctly assigns the labels.

```
import pandas as pd
values = [5100,5400,9400,10000,16000,10500,0,0,0,87500,14000,11250]
d = {'continuous': values,'label': [0]*6+[1]*6}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
bins = [-1, 0, 5000000]
df['discrete'] = pd.cut(df['continuous'], bins=bins)

print(pd.crosstab(df.discrete, df.label))
```

Gives the desired output

```
label         0  1
discrete          
(-1, 0]       0  3
(0, 5000000]  6  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your efforts. But I just killed and restarted the kernel, opened a new notebook, and copy pasted code from your comment without changing, and I still get the same swapped-label error, 

`label         0  1

discrete          

(0, 5000000]  0  3

(-1, 0]       6  3`

(pd version 0.23.0)

Comment: Can you update to pandas version 0.23.2? I have been able to recreate your error on 0.23.0 but it seems resolved in 0.23.2. You can do this in anaconda prompt with `conda install pandas=0.23.2`

Comment: Great, it works now, thank you! I'll accept your answer. Perhaps you could edit it to include the instructions to upgrade to 0.23.2 in the main answer for greater visibility in case anyone else has this problem. I'm also curious if anyone has any idea why this happened in older versions? Doesn't seem desirable behaviour. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3140106 looks like quite a few changes around categorical types in pandas recently - the bin labels are a category type so can only imagine it was a problem there. It worked fine in my original version of 0.22, so something must have regressed in 0.23 and then fixed in later releases.